# How to permanently delete my Facebook application

Tags: facebook, search

I have created a Facebook application that I don't want to use anymore. I deleted it from my developer account and from the related Facebook page more than a week ago but it still appears in the Facebook search engine.

I know similar questions have been posted, but I have no longer access to the admin of this application, meaning I can't change the user accessibility of the app.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug by Facebook. You might want to post a bug report [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/). A solution which might help next time: Switch on the sandbox mode, then delete the app.